# How to link external css file affecting only on 1 div and unaffecting all other divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Pardon me if the question is absurd. I need to do something like this.

I have this two external `css` files in my `html` document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mdb.css">
```

There is a `form` in my html as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>New Affiliate Signup</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>  
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**mdb.css** - contains the same classes and Ids as that of `bootstrap.css` but they have been manipulated to give advanced visual effects (hovering,button colors, shadow colors and other advanced features) **without affecting the core content of the `bootstrap.css`**

But I don't need `mdb.css` to affect in my `<form>` yet I still need it for other elements in my `<html>` document (Headers, Carousels etc...)

Since I have already linked the `mdb.css` it will affect all the elements including `<form>`.

**Can I only be able to link `bootstrap.css` to my `<form>` without linking `mdb.css` and without removing `mdb.css` inside `<head>`**

Like putting a `<div>` around `<form>` and setting only the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet to that `<div>`?

Please someone help me?

Comment: You are right it does sound absurd. Two stylesheets with the same classes and Ids are going to conflict no matter what unless one of them specifies the !important rule on specific classes/ids. If it doesnt, whichever stylesheet is applied last will have priority. bottom line: *Consider rewriting your mdb.css class*

Comment: Isn't there a way we can do that without changing the stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one solution could be to add a class "without-mdb" to your form and add ":not(.without-mdb)

Comment: Well, your form field should be  _<form class="form-horizonta without-mdb">_ and in your mdb.css file, if you have for example _form a{color:ed;}_, you can modify it by _form:not(.without-mdb) a {color:red}_

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply CSS files to elements. You apply CSS rules from CSS files to elements.

To keep the bootstrap styles of your `<form>` element AND keep both CSS files without changes in the head section, you will have to add a specific selector to the `<form>` (like 
 a class `.no-mdb`) and notate some additional CSS rules with [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), that revert the mdb styles to the bootstrap styles.

Here is a working example:

```css
.no-mdb {
  /* your reverting styles go here.
     make sure your styles have a higher specificity to properly overwrite your existing styles */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <form class="no-mdb">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Nevertheless the better approach would be, to properly handle the form in your *mdb.css*.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just add individual classes to your mdb.css stylesheet that do what you want it to do and include it within your element? Rather than trying to update standard bootstrap classes.

This is the simpler option but would require some refactoring of your mdb.css stylesheet.

**Example**

```css
.redBackground
{
  /* !important rule overrides any existing styles on the element */
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>New Affiliate Signup</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <!-- Add the new css class as additional class in your markup !-->
                    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md redBackground" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```